# Grails download file from smb

Tags: grails, download, smb

How can I provide a download of a remote file?
The file can be accessed via SMB (jcifs). I can read the properties of the files. But how to send it to the users browser?

This does not work:

```
render(contentType: 'application/zip',file: new File(FullPath), fileName: domainInstance.getFilename())
```

Where full path is like smb://user:pass@server.domain.com/root/Files/Dowanload.zip

Accessing the file via works:

```
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(FullPath ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your controller:

```
                SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(FullPath )//,auth);

                if (smbFile.exists()) {
                   response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
                   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${domainInstance.getFilename()}")
                   response.setContentLength(Long.valueOf(smbFile.length()).intValue())
                   response.outputStream << smbFile.getInputStream()    
                   response.outputStream.flush()
                   return       
}
```

It works fine in latest Grails 2.4.4!